# Is it possible to stretch the input field by giving rows={3} using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-chips for displaying email into chips "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chips". Here my objective is to stretch the chip input field like rows={3} column={20}. but Couldn't able to find how to give in react-chips. Is it possible to stretch the respective field? can anyone help me in this query?

Here is the code:

```
 <Container>
        <Modal trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}>
          <Modal.Content>
            <Form>
              <strong>Email</strong>
              <Chips
                className="f_input"
                value={this.state.chips}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                suggestions={["Your", "Data", "Here"]}
                chipTheme={{
                  chip: {
                    border: "none",
                    borderBottom: "1px solid black"
                  },
                  chipRemove: {
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    color: "green",
                    ":hover": {
                      color: "yellow"
                    }
                  }
                }}
              />
              <Form.Field
                transparent
                className="f_input"
                control={Input}
                label="Subject"
              />

              <TextArea placeholder="Email Format" />
            </Form>

            <Button>Send</Button>
          </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
      </Container>
```

[Here is the whole code](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-yalow-sx678)

Can anyone please help me in stretching the chip input field?

Comment: why not go with height or widht?

Comment: Hey! What do you mean by stretching? I tried your code and can't understand what you mean :/

Comment: @Abhishek-Saini - Hi, I've tried giving minHeight: '150px' but it is not working in my code

Comment: @PedroFilipe - Hi, I mean - i want to make input field to be bit long similar to `Text Area` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Chips` component accepts a prop called `theme` in which you can change the `input` CSS. Add this to your `Chips` component and play around a bit:

```
 theme={{
   chipsContainer: {
     width: "100%",
     minHeight: 150,
     display: "flex",
     flexWrap: "wrap",
     border: "1px solid #ccc",
     alignContent: "flex-start"
   },
   container: {
     flex: 1
   },
   input: {
     border: "none"
   }
 }}
```

And in your `chipTheme` your `chip` should be like this:

```
chip: {
  border: "none",
  borderBottom: "1px solid black",
  height: 24
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/gregchamberlain/react-chips/blob/master/src/theme.js
- https://github.com/gregchamberlain/react-chips#styles

Comment: I applied the above one, I'm facing 2 issues: 1. Cursor is appearing in the middle, not from 1st line onward. 2: When i type any email and then enter, it is out of the input field.